# Monitor log file on aws docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I currently have the following setup:

I have multiple AWS EC2 instances, each running a Docker container within which I continuously various simulations. The simulations' output is written to a .log file, where lines are added every few seconds. Right now, to check the output state I have to manually ssh into the instances, open the containers in interactive mode (bash), cd to the directory containing the log file and tail the file. It's fine, but rather laborious.

I would like some way of monitoring this more easily. The only thing I can think is to have a script that runs every -n seconds (eg: Every 2 minutes) and sends the file to an HTTP server or S3 bucket. I was wondering however if AWS had some quicker/out-of-the-box setup for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a CloudWatch agent on your EC2 instances.